# <audio> error event does not fire on MacOS Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, html5-audio

I'm making an audio player, and found that my `<audio>` tag does not fire `error` event on MacOS Safari, when loading a `webm` audio file. The webm file codec is opus.

```html
<audio id="audioPlayer"      
      controls
      controlsList="nodownload noplaybackrate"
      preload="metadata"
      src="myAudioFile.webm"
      type="audio/webm">
```

My error handing script:

```js
const player = document.getElementById('audioPlayer')
player.addEventListener('error', function (e) {
      console.log('audio error:', e)
})
player.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function (e) {
      console.log('audio loadedmetadata:', e)
})
player.addEventListener('loadeddata', function (e) {
      console.log('audio loadeddata:', e)
})
```

On Firefox, Edge, and Chrome, the webm audio file could play.

On MacOS Safari 16.1, `loadedmetadata` and `loadeddata` event are firing. But the audio does not play, nor `error` event.

On iOS Safari, `error` event fires normally.

**Question:**
How could I properly get error event on MacOS Safari?